# SDL_Window was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl-2

I'm doing a tutorial on SDL, and I'm having some issues
I just did [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php) where I do the basic stuff to get SDL to run. I then ran the test code (which is on that page) and it worked. However, now I'm trying to run the code [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php), and it's giving me [this](http://pastebin.com/vZYpQBP3) list of errors.

What could be the problem? There was one weird thing, I don't know if it's relevant, to get the first code running I had to put `SDL2.dll` in the `SysWOW64` folder even though both my compiler and version of the library are 32-bit. Again, I haven't a clue whether that could mean anything, especially because I got the first thing to run perfectly.

Edit: Also, Code::Blocks shows me the error in `SDL_platform.h`, a file completely identical to my `01_hello_SDL.cpp`. I'm a complete noob to SDL and even though I have done some pure C++ I haven't used it with an external library before, so I have no idea what that means.

Edit: Here's my setup:
I copied the contents of the 32 bit folder to `C:\mingw_dev_lib\sdl`, resulting in `C:\mingw_dev_lib\sdl\bin`, `C:\mingw_dev_lib\sdl\include`, `C:\mingw_dev_lib\sdl\lib` and `C:\mingw_dev_lib\sdl\share`.
I copied `SDL2.dll` to both `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

In Code::Blocks my setup is like this: In `build options`, in the `linker settings` tab I put `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`. In the `search directories` tab, in the `Compiler` subtab I have `C:\mingw_dev_lib\sdl\include\SDL2` and in the `Linker` subtab I have `C:\mingw_dev_lib\sdl\lib`.

This got the test (which you can find at bottom of the page of first link) to work. However, the second program (at the bottom of the page of second link) gives me the errors in the third link.

Comment: Your `SDL_platform.h` is broken. Where have you got it? Use headers from archive downloaded from libsdl.org. dlls wouldn't get you compilation error so it isn't relevant here.

Comment: I don't know how it could have happened, but my SDL_platform.h was indeed broken. By replacing it the problem was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SDL or SDL**2** ?  I had to include `SDL2/SDL.h`, but previously I was having the same error as you report.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to put `SDL2.dll` in the `SysWOW64` folder because you're linking *SDL2* dynamically and when you execute the program it needs to find the `SDL2.dll` file in basically two folders:

1. The folder where the program resides.
2. `System32` (or his 64 bit counterpart `SysWOW64`).

Therefore i can't give you an accurate answer based on the compilation errors you get, please show how you're including SDL2 and the *Code::Blocks* configuration.

Comment: I edited my original post to include data about my configuration. Is this the info you are looking for?